# Llama_index index.query returns proper response when .py file is run via CLI but return "None" when used with (Django)api call

Tags: python, django, nonetype, openai-api, llama-index

I am trying to het a response from openai.
This works fine when I run the file form the CLI.(see code below)
Because it prints the response to the command line.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
import os


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "<MY_OPENAI_API_KEY>"

@csrf_exempt
def ask_ai( prompt ):
    print( prompt )
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.from_documents( documents )

    response = index.query( prompt )
    print(  response )



ask_ai("<my prompt>")
```

However, when I use Django to call the mostly the same but slightly modified file(see below) the response is always printed as "None" and returned as null.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
import os


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "<MY_OPENAI_API_KEY>"

@csrf_exempt
def ask_ai( prompt ):
    print( prompt )
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.from_documents( documents )

    response = index.query( prompt )
    print(  response )
    return  response.response
```

What can I do to make it print/return the response for the API call in the same way that it does for the CLI?

I have tried:

- async/await. This returns an error. *TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable*
- adding a second function with async await applied that returns the query response to ask_ai which then returns it to the requester but this results in the same type error
- printing/returning as string *str(response)*
- returning as json

I was hoping to have the code print and return the expected response to *index.query(prompt)*